# Passing variable to jQuery .load function

Tags: jquery, function, variables, load

can I pass variable (variable named test in this case) to jQuery .load function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var test= $(this).attr('href');
        $('.window').load($(test));     

});
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: You mentioned that you wanted to load an external URL in one of your comments. But load is under a restriction such that "the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrapping your url in a call to jQuery.  Just pass `test`, not `$(test)`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var test= $(this).attr('href');
        $('.window').load(test);        
    });
});
```

Also, you are missing the closing `});` in your sample code.  Not sure if it's a typo here or in your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `test` is a string. `.load` should take that string, not a jQuery object.

```
$('.window').load(test);
```

ought to work.

Comment: As a side note, however, it's probably a bad idea to use "window" as a class name. Even if it never conflicts with anything in JavaScript, it may mislead someone new who reads your code.